# WinForms - Disable default mouse hover over item behaviour?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, mouseevent, onmouseover

I have a `ComboBox` with items in it. I also have a `SelectedIndexChange` event.
When I open the `ComboBox` and hover over an item, the `SelectedIndex` property seems to change to that item. I'd only like it to change when I click on the item. Is it possible to disable that behavior?

I have a timer that refreshes an `Image` based on `SelectedIndex` of `ComboBox`,  but still, even if I highlight an item but don't select, why does the `Image` changes while it should not change and it only should change when I select an item.

Comment: I have an Image in my program that changes the Image's 'Image' property's value with the combobox. When I highlight the item, the Image changes to that value for some reason. I only want to do that when I click on the item. (also, when highlighting an item, it seems to skip some code or something, as it does not display the panel it's supposed to display and goes on to calling loadImage() )

Comment: Can you debug application by setting breakpoint in `SelectedIndexChange` event handler and hovering over `ComboBox` ? Does breakpoint hit?

Comment: No, it only triggers when I click. I figured out a part of the problem, I have a timer that refreshes the image every x seconds. But still, even if I highlight an item, why does the image change to that value? It should not, it only should when I click.
(also the timer's event is set to refresh the image to the value of the combobox.SelectedIndex)

Comment: what the timer does is `image.LoadAsync(Properties.Settings.Default.image_urls[combobox.SelectedIndex]);`

Comment: `SelectedIndexChanged` doesn't fire but the `SelectedIndex` really changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Problem**

When the the mouse moves on items of `ComboBox`, the `SelectedIndex` changes but `SelectedIndexChanged` event doesn't fire, so in your timer `Tick` event, you will see the change while `SelectedIndexChanged` doesn't fire.

**Scenario of reproducing the problem**

To simply reproduce the problem, put a `Timer` on a form and enable it, then handle its `Tick` event. Also add a `ComboBox` and add some items to it and handle its `SelectedIndexChanged` event. When you open the dropdown and move mouse over items, you will see the `Text` of form changes to the index of item that is under the cursor, while `SelectedIndexChanged` doesn't fire and no `MessageBox` will show.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString());
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
}
```

**The Solution for your case**

You can simply check if the dropdown is not open using [`DroppedDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.droppeddown(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `ComboBox`, then do the job:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!this.comboBox1.DroppedDown)
        this.Text = this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `SelectedIndex` changing on mouse hover - Is this a .NET bug? Or is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: @pius I am also very interested in whether the behavior is documented. IMO this "problem" could definitely be used on the side of good as I have managed to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72788611/5438626).