# Get correct bound of combobox item when owner drawing

Tags: c#, winforms

I used:

```cs
myComboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
```

Then I implemented the `DrawItem` event like so:

```cs
private void myComboBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index < 0)
        return;

    string text = myComboBox.GetItemText(myComboBox.Items[e.Index]);
    e.DrawBackground();
    using var brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font!, brush, e.Bounds);
    if (myComboBox.DroppedDown && (e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
    {
        var item = (IndexedItem)myComboBox.Items[e.Index]; // IndexedItem is my own class to hold the index and name of a combobox item

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Name))
            myToolTip.Show(item.Name, myComboBox, e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom);
    }
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

The purpose is to show a tooltip for each item when I hover it. The above code works fine but sometimes the dropdown is shown above instead of below due to available space.

The problem now is, that `DrawBackground` etc use the adjusted positions but `e.Bounds` still contains the area below the control. So the dropdown is shown above but the tooltip below the combobox. I guess `DrawBackground` modifies the bounds internally but doesn't write the adjusted value back to `e.Bounds`. Now the question is, how can I determine the correct bounds of the item in that case?

Comment: [Raise an event when I hover the mouse over a ComboBox item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61154093/7444103) - If you're targeting .Net Framework 4.8 or .Net 5+, you just need to override WndProc of a custom Control and trap `CB_GETCURSEL`. The sample code raises an event when you hover the mouse over an item in the ListControl. There's also an alternative method .Net versions prior to 4.8 (where `CB_GETCURSEL` is never received). -- You should try to show a ToolTip in the `DrawItem` handler. IMO, since this extends the functionality, you should use a Custom Control.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to find the correct bounds via interops like this:

```cs
Rectangle GetItemBounds(int index)
{
    const int SB_VERT = 0x1;
    const int SIF_RANGE = 0x1;
    const int SIF_POS = 0x4;
    const uint GETCOMBOBOXINFO = 0x0164;

    var info = new COMBOBOXINFO();
    info.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(info);
    SendMessageW(
        myComboBox.Handle,
        GETCOMBOBOXINFO,
        IntPtr.Zero,
        ref info);
    GetWindowRect(info.hwndList, out RECT rc);
    var dropdownArea = new Rectangle(myComboBox.PointToClient(rc.Location), rc.Size);
    int yDiff = index * myComboBox.ItemHeight;
    var scrollInfo = new SCROLLINFO();
    scrollInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(scrollInfo);
    scrollInfo.fMask = SIF_RANGE | SIF_POS;
    GetScrollInfo(info.hwndList, SB_VERT, ref scrollInfo);
    int scrollY = scrollInfo.nPos * myComboBox.ItemHeight;
    return new Rectangle(dropdownArea.X, dropdownArea.Y - scrollY + yDiff, rc.Width, myComboBox.ItemHeight);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```cs
var realBounds = GetItemBounds(e.Index);
```

I am not sure if this is the best approach but it even works with scrolling inside the dropdown now.

The interops look like this:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct COMBOBOXINFO
{
    public Int32 cbSize;
    public RECT rcItem, rcButton;
    public int buttonState;
    public IntPtr hwndCombo, hwndEdit, hwndList;
}

[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SCROLLINFO
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public uint fMask;
    public int nMin;
    public int nMax;
    public uint nPage;
    public int nPos;
    public int nTrackPos;
}

[DllImport("user32")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool GetScrollInfo(IntPtr hwnd, int fnBar, ref SCROLLINFO lpsi);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;

    public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        Left = left;
        Top = top;
        Right = right;
        Bottom = bottom;
    }

    public RECT(System.Drawing.Rectangle r) : this(r.Left, r.Top, r.Right, r.Bottom) { }

    public int X
    {
        get { return Left; }
        set { Right -= (Left - value); Left = value; }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get { return Top; }
        set { Bottom -= (Top - value); Top = value; }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get { return Bottom - Top; }
        set { Bottom = value + Top; }
    }

    public int Width
    {
        get { return Right - Left; }
        set { Right = value + Left; }
    }

    public System.Drawing.Point Location
    {
        get { return new System.Drawing.Point(Left, Top); }
        set { X = value.X; Y = value.Y; }
    }

    public System.Drawing.Size Size
    {
        get { return new System.Drawing.Size(Width, Height); }
        set { Width = value.Width; Height = value.Height; }
    }

    public static implicit operator System.Drawing.Rectangle(RECT r)
    {
        return new System.Drawing.Rectangle(r.Left, r.Top, r.Width, r.Height);
    }

    public static implicit operator RECT(System.Drawing.Rectangle r)
    {
        return new RECT(r);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(RECT r1, RECT r2)
    {
        return r1.Equals(r2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(RECT r1, RECT r2)
    {
        return !r1.Equals(r2);
    }

    public bool Equals(RECT r)
    {
        return r.Left == Left && r.Top == Top && r.Right == Right && r.Bottom == Bottom;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if (obj is RECT)
            return Equals((RECT)obj);
        else if (obj is System.Drawing.Rectangle)
            return Equals(new RECT((System.Drawing.Rectangle)obj));
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ((System.Drawing.Rectangle)this).GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{{Left={0},Top={1},Right={2},Bottom={3}}}", Left, Top, Right, Bottom);
    }
}

[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT rc);

[DllImport("user32", ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(
    IntPtr hWnd,
    uint Msg,
    IntPtr wParam = default,
    IntPtr lParam = default);

public unsafe static IntPtr SendMessageW<T>(
    IntPtr hWnd,
    uint Msg,
    IntPtr wParam,
    ref T lParam) where T : unmanaged
{
    fixed (void* l = &lParam)
    {
        return SendMessageW(hWnd, Msg, wParam, (IntPtr)l);
    }
}
```

I created an extension:

```cs
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    public static class ComboBoxExtensions
    {
        public static Rectangle GetItemBounds(this ComboBox comboBox, int index)
        {
            const int SB_VERT = 0x1;
            const int SIF_RANGE = 0x1;
            const int SIF_POS = 0x4;
            const uint GETCOMBOBOXINFO = 0x0164;

            var info = new Interop.COMBOBOXINFO();
            info.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(info);
            Interop.SendMessageW(
                comboBox.Handle,
                GETCOMBOBOXINFO,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                ref info);
            Interop.GetWindowRect(info.hwndList, out Interop.RECT rc);
            var dropdownArea = new Rectangle(comboBox.PointToClient(rc.Location), rc.Size);
            int yDiff = index * comboBox.ItemHeight;
            var scrollInfo = new Interop.SCROLLINFO();
            scrollInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(scrollInfo);
            scrollInfo.fMask = SIF_RANGE | SIF_POS;
            Interop.GetScrollInfo(info.hwndList, SB_VERT, ref scrollInfo);
            int scrollY = scrollInfo.nPos * comboBox.ItemHeight;
            return new Rectangle(dropdownArea.X, dropdownArea.Y - scrollY + yDiff, rc.Width, comboBox.ItemHeight);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

***I realize you have already answered your own question. This is just plan B.***

Your post mentions that **the purpose is to show a tooltip for each item when I hover it** so this answer focuses on that aspect. It doesn't make use of the item bounds info but that would be available in the `DrawItem` handler if you still need it.

This approach is loosely based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33698213/5438626) and takes advantage of  `comboBox.SelectedItem` property changing (but without firing an event) as the mouse moves over the dropped-down list. It uses that change to draw tool tips on an owner-draw combo box (only it doesn't *have* to be an owner-draw combo box for it to work).

[image: combo box with tool tips]

This sample code for `MainForm` starts a timer when the `ComboBox` drops and ends it when it closes. It polls the `SelectedIndex` property on each tick.

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();            
    // Works with or without owner draw.
    // This line may be commented out
    comboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    // Add items
    foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ComboBoxItems)))
        comboBox.Items.Add(item);
    // Start timer on drop down
    comboBox.DropDown += (sender, e) => _toolTipTimer.Enabled = true;
    // End timer on closed
    comboBox.DropDownClosed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        _toolTipTimer.Enabled = false; 
        _lastToolTipIndex = -1;
        _toolTip.Hide(comboBox);
    };
    // Poll index while open
    _toolTipTimer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if(comboBox.SelectedIndex != _lastToolTipIndex)
        {
            _lastToolTipIndex = comboBox.SelectedIndex;
            showToolTip();
        }
    };
```

If there is a new index, the local method `showToolTip` is invoked to show the correct text.

```
    void showToolTip()
    {
        if (_lastToolTipIndex != -1)
        {
            // Get the item
            var item = (ComboBoxItems)comboBox.Items[_lastToolTipIndex];
            // Get the tip
            var tt = TipAttribute.FromMember(item);
            // Get the rel pos
            var mousePosition = PointToClient(MousePosition);
            var rel = new Point(
                (mousePosition.X - comboBox.Location.X) - 10,
                (mousePosition.Y - comboBox.Location.Y) - 30);
            // Show the tip
            _toolTip.Show(tt, comboBox, rel);
        }
    }
}
private ToolTip _toolTip = new ToolTip();
private readonly Timer _toolTipTimer = new Timer() { Interval = 100 };
private int _lastToolTipIndex = -1;
```

The list items are represented by this `enum`:

```
enum ComboBoxItems
{
    [Tip("...a day keeps the doctor away")]
    Apple,
    [Tip("...you glad I didn't say 'banana?'")]
    Orange,
    [Tip("...job on the Tool Tips!")]
    Grape,
}
```

Where `TipAttribute` is defined as:

```
internal class TipAttribute : Attribute
{
    public TipAttribute(string tip) => Tip = tip;
    public string Tip { get; }
    public static string FromMember(Enum value) =>
        ((TipAttribute)value
            .GetType()
            .GetMember($"{value}")
            .Single()
            .GetCustomAttribute(typeof(TipAttribute))).Tip;
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/combo_box_tooltip.git) this sample.